# richtextbox does not append text immediately

Tags: c#, winforms

When I click on the button, I am starting simulation.

During simulation I want to append to `richTextBox` items. Loop looks something like this. (`Output` is a `RichTextBox`).

```
while (!battleEnded) 
{
    BattleExchange(bh, Left, Right, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    if (Right.Health <= 0)
    {
        Right.Health = 0;
        Output.AppendText(String.Format(Announcements.PERSON_DIED, Right.Name));
        break;
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    BattleExchange(bh, Right, Left, System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
    if (Left.Health <= 0)
    {
        Left.Health = 0;
        Output.AppendText(String.Format(Announcements.PERSON_DIED, Left.Name));
    }
    ....
}
```

But  the problem is that when I click on the button and start simulation - text does not appear immediately, but only after the simulation has ended.

What's the problem?
My button click event looks like this

```
richTextBox1.Clear();
fight.SimulateBattle();
```

By the way when I used multiline `textbox` it worked properly.

Comment: Why did you insert this delay: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); ?

Comment: The UI thread is being blocked. You need to spin this stuff off in another thread.

Comment: @AlexBell, because I want to add messages every second (because other way it will end quickly)

Comment: So, that is the reason for "richtextbox does not append text immediately" (see the second BattleExchange() following that Thread.Sleep(1000)); it seems like you have intentionally inserted such delay, blocking the execution. Please clarify your business logic. Thanks and regards,

Comment: During `Thread.Sleep(1000);` nothing will happen in the UI thread. Make sure to insert a `Output.Refresh` __before__ hitting the `Sleep`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, the main problem is that you are running this loop in the UI thread, preventing any of the UI logic from operating. This is a huge "don't do that" in Winforms and pretty much any other of the mainstream GUI platforms.

Code executing in the UI thread should do very little and be very quick. You should *never* block in the UI thread (e.g. call `Thread.Sleep()`), and should move any long-running execution of code into a separate thread.

I *strongly* advise against using the `Control.Refresh()` method. That's just a hack to work around more fundamental problems with your code as-designed.

Lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario, it's impossible to know what the *best* fix would be. But assuming you're using the latest version of .NET and C#, and assuming the `BattleExchange()` method itself executes reasonably quickly, the simplest fix I can think of would be to make your `SimulateBattle()` method an `async` method and use `Task.Delay()` for the one-second delay in the middle of the loop:

```
async void SimulateBattle()
{
    while (!battleEnded) 
    {
        BattleExchange(bh, Left, Right, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        if (Right.Health <= 0)
        {
            Right.Health = 0;
            Output.AppendText(String.Format(Announcements.PERSON_DIED, Right.Name));
            break;
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        BattleExchange(bh, Right, Left, System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
        if (Left.Health <= 0)
        {
            Left.Health = 0;
            Output.AppendText(String.Format(Announcements.PERSON_DIED, Left.Name));
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

**Note:** typically, one should not use `void` as the return type for an async method, because it prevents the method from being awaitable, which in turn prevents the calling code from being able to catch exceptions and otherwise monitor the state of the async task. However, in this case I feel that `void` can be used without making the code any worse; it already (apparently) doesn't catch or report exceptions anyway, and so ignoring them here doesn't change anything.

Other possible fixes include running the code in `BackgroundWorker` and using `ProgressChanged` to update the `Output` text, or just creating a new thread or task explicitly and using some cross-thread invocation mechanism to update the `Output` text (e.g. `Control.Invoke()`, or using the `Progress<T>` class).